# Pyflakes reports an invalid syntax error in a print command

Tags: python, pyflakes

Pyflakes reports an invalid syntax error in a print (to file) command in a class method.  Here is the code:

```
class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = ''
        self.permissions = None
        self.url = ''
        self.description = ''
        self.requests = ''
        self.url_params = ''
        self.data = ''
        self.response = ''
        self.pagination = ''
        self.cmd_file = None
        self.json_file = None
        self.html_file = None
        self.dict_file = None
        self.app_name = ''
        self.app = None
    def json_doc(self):
        if self.permissions:
            permissions = self.permissions + '.'
        else:
            permissions = ''
        print(
            '{\n' \
            '\t"URL": "' + self.url + '",\n' \
            '\t"Description": "' + self.description + '.",\n' \
            '\t"Requests": "' + self.requests + '",\n' \
            '\t"Permissions": "' + permissions + '",\n' \
            '\t"URL Parameters": "' + self.url_params + '",\n' \
            '\t"Data": "' + self.data + '",\n' \
            '\t"Response": "' + self.response + '",\n' \
            '\t"Pagination": "' + self.pagination + '"\n' \
            '}', \
            file=self.json_file
        )
```

Here is the error:

```
curl_doc.py:79:17: invalid syntax
            file=self.json_file
                ^
```

json_file is set elsewhere in my code.  It seems to be a problem with pyflakes as the code runs OK.  The pyflakes command used was:

```
pyflakes curl_doc.py
```

Comment: Are you using a Pyflakes version that matches your Python version?

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

remove that back slash here and you are fine:

```
'}', \
file=self.json_file
```

Answer (score 0):

print("your name contains " + new_num_char +  " characters".)
i wrote the above code,and the error was syntax error , it took me about an hour to figure out that my fullstop was outside the quotes.
so in my own opinion, pyflakes E syntax error actually mean syntax error; you just have to check your code again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I updated Pyflakes from version 0.8.1 to version 1.2.3 and the problem went away:

```
pip install --upgrade pyflakes
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>